# Neural network does not give out the required out put?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

Made a neural network using tensor flows that was supposed matches an Ip to one of the 7 type of vulnerabilities and gives out what type of vulnerability that IP has.

---

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])



model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500)
```

The output of `print(model.predict([181271844]))` when this command is executed should be one of the numbers from 1 to 7 but the out put its gives is

> [[0.22288103 0.20282331 0.36847615 0.11339897 0.04456346 0.02391759
>     0.02393949]]

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: xs is the list of IPs and ys is its corrensponding vulnerability from 0 to 6 (seven in total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you are seeing as output are a *probability vector*. This is a common output format for multi-class classification models.

In this case, you can interpret the vector as saying:

- 22% chance of class 1
- 20% chance of class 2
- 37% chance of class 3
- 11% chance of class 4
- 4% chance of class 5
- 2% chance of class 6
- 2% chance of class 7

If you want to get a concrete label out of this, the easiest choice is to compute and return the index of the maximum element.